# After reloading <div> with jQuery, whole my site moves to the left and looks broken

Tags: javascript, php, api

I have used the follow code to reload the content in my `<div>`

```
function loadlink(){
    $('#prices').load('prices.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 15 seconds
}, 15000);
```

But after it hits the 15 seconds mark, my whole site moves to the left and looks broken. What am I doing wrong here?

Basic information:

```
<div id="prices">
<?php include 'prices.php';?>
</div>
```

prices.php contains some html elements and the php code to fetch the prices from an api.

ANSWER: REMOVE `$(this).unwrap();`if you don't want your code that aligns to be removed!

Comment: What is in prices.php?

Comment: You're removing the `<div align="center">` that wraps everything... try `$('#prices').load('prices.php');`

Comment: Note your response doesn't include a `<div id="prices">` parent so there is no need for the `unwrap()` code which as Chris points out is actually removing the parent `<center>` tag

Comment: wew... I suck so hard -_- Thanks guys <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the first div in your response, try this:

```
function loadlink(){
    $('#prices').load('prices.php');
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 15 seconds
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but uhm.. do you know how to show a (very) short fade in effect? So my users will now we fetched the prices again and they are up to date? If I recall correctly, there should be like a fadeIn function with js? I tried     $('#links').load('prices.php').fadeIn(); but nothing happens :(